# Using spry menu to create master page

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, spry

Dreamweaver has spry menu function which lets user creating navigation bar quickly.
Suppose I have multiple pages in a web site, the navigation bar are all same.
Can we borrow the concept of master page from asp.net?
I mean that to create master page by using spry menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>With pure html/css ... No you can't.</s>

With the use of PHP, ASP, or a similar server side technology you could.

---

On second thought maybe you could use AJAX to load the menu in with the jQuery library.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#menu').load('menu.html');
```

So add jQuery to your web page. Then add the script above and where currently have the Spry menu put...

```
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Put the code for the menu you just removed into a file called menu.html.